# XML parse to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a large XML file into a two-column pandas dataframe. I see a number of examples here, but am an amateur and cannot seem to adapt one to my use case after much trying.

How can I do this efficiently? I have about a million of these in my file.

Starting XML:

```
  <Site id="99" action="visit" date="11-Jul-2021">
    <SiteType>Production</SiteType>
    <Status>Inactive</Status>
    <ItemDetails>
      <Item ItemType="A">
        <ItemValue Code="AA"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemType="B">
        <ItemValue Code="BB"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemType="C">
        <ItemValue Code="CC"/>
      </Item>
    </ItemDetails>
  </Site>
```

Desired Output is a two-col dataframe that contains the Site id and ItemValue Code from ItemType="C"

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZmu.png)

Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please improve your question with details on what you researched, how you tried to solve your problem and why/where are you stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would start with the pandas `read_xml()` method, but in this it looks like the xml is going to be too complex for that. So you may have to go the longer way around - first parse the xml and then create the dataframe.

So assuming you have two sites and your xml looks like the below:

```
site = """<sites>
  <Site id="99" action="visit" date="11-Jul-2021">
    <SiteType>Production</SiteType>
    <Status>Inactive</Status>
    <ItemDetails>
      <Item ItemType="A">
        <ItemValue Code="AA"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemType="B">
        <ItemValue Code="BB"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemType="C">
        <ItemValue Code="CC"/>
      </Item>
    </ItemDetails>
  </Site>
  <Site id="100" action="visit" date="11-Jul-2021">
    <SiteType>Production</SiteType>
    <Status>Inactive</Status>
    <ItemDetails>
      <Item ItemType="A">
        <ItemValue Code="AA"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemType="B">
        <ItemValue Code="BB"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemType="C">
        <ItemValue Code="DD"/>
      </Item>
    </ItemDetails>
  </Site>
  </sites>"""
```

Do this:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

doc = etree.fromstring(site)
rows = []
for iv in doc.xpath('//Site'):
    rows.append([iv.xpath('./@id')[0],iv.xpath('.//Item[@ItemType="C"]/ItemValue/@Code')[0]])
columns = ["Site id", "IV Code"]
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    Site id IV Code
0   99      CC
1   100     DD
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, and I understand the loop logic. One follow up question - how can I pass my XML file instead of declaring it in a cell? I created an XML file in notepad with the sample data, but cannot get around this error: XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Comment: @ulanmitar Usually, to parse an xml file you use `doc = etree.parse(file)`. Not sure about the error you're getting with notepad.